# Exclude mobile updates from "presenceUpdate" event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

When using the "presenceUpdate" event in discord.js, it is successfully being fired when a status changes from "nothing" to "streaming". However, it seems as though, if I open the mobile client after the event is triggered, it happens again, with the exact same "oldUser" and "newUser". I'm using VSCode and running my node.js instance through there locally, so I am able to use breakpoints to debug.

```
client.on("presenceUpdate", (oldUser, newUser) => {
    //Exclude title changes and typing
    if(oldUser.presence.game != null && oldUser.presence.game.streaming) {
        return;
    }

    if(oldUser.displayName === "Test" && newUser.presence != null){
        if(newUser.presence.game != null && newUser.presence.game.streaming){
            client.channels.get("channelId").send("@everyone Test has started streaming!");               
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see, I have attempted to filter this "double-trigger" already with the first if block. This is not successful, because it looks like the first time it is triggered, the old and new user are exactly the same as the second time it triggers. The only difference I could tell is that the "clientStatus" now includes "mobile: online" as a property. Is there any way to prevent this double trigger in the first place, code-wise, or will I need to make better filters on my if statements?

Answer (score 1):

See [`Presence.clientStatus`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence?scrollTo=clientStatus); it'll return what type of device a presence applies to.

Using this property, you can compare the old user's client with the new user's client and return if it has changed.

```js
if (oldUser.presence.clientStatus !== newUser.presence.clientStatus) return;
```

Comment: I believe this is a piece to the puzzle. However, after testing it with this added, I'm still getting a double-output. I'm starting to think that it doesn't actually have to do with the mobile version necessarily and is instead a bug with discord.js. I'll keep digging.

Comment: For clarity, this is discord.js version 11.5.1. https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/2481 I found this, which is explaining the exact issue I was having, but it seems to be back?

Comment: @Clavaat The event would still be emitted for client status changes as it's a property of Presence, but this solution should just stop the listener.

Comment: "...there were 2 instance of [D]iscord going on and it hit that event emmitter twice because of it." If your presence is from mobile *and* the desktop client or web client, this may cause your issue. It seems like a bug to me.

Comment: I made sure I wasn't connected to the mobile client when I attempted to trigger the event and, even with the added conditional, it still double-posted.